# Testing a potential deadlock without sleep in JUnit

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, deadlock, synchronized

In classical Deadlock example, there are two paths in the code acquiring the same two synchronized locks, but in different order like here:

```
// Production code
public class Deadlock {
    final private Object monitor1;
    final private Object monitor2;

    public Deadlock(Object monitor1, Object monitor2) {
        this.monitor1 = monitor1;
        this.monitor2 = monitor2;
    }

    public void method1() {
        synchronized (monitor1) {
            tryToSleep(1000);
            synchronized (monitor2) {
                tryToSleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public void method2() {
        synchronized (monitor2) {
            tryToSleep(1000);
            synchronized (monitor1) {
                tryToSleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void tryToSleep(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This could potentially result in a deadlock. To increase the chance that it actually deadlocks, I am adding those `tryToSleep(1000);`, just to ensure that method1 will acquire a lock on monitor1, and method2 will acquire the lock on monitor2, before even trying to acquire next lock. So using the sleep this Deadlock simulates "unlucky" timing. Say, there is a strange requirement, that our code should have the potential to result in a deadlock, and for that reason, we want to test it:

```
   // Test
   @Test
    void callingBothMethodsWillDeadlock() {
        var deadlock = new Deadlock(Integer.class, String.class);

        var t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            deadlock.method1(); // Executes for at least 1000ms
        });
        t1.start();

        var t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            deadlock.method2(); // Executes for at least 1000ms
        });
        t2.start();

        Deadlock.tryToSleep(5000); // We need to wait for 2s + 2s + some more to be sure...

        assertEquals(Thread.State.BLOCKED, t1.getState());
        assertTrue(t1.isAlive());

        assertEquals(Thread.State.BLOCKED, t2.getState());
        assertTrue(t2.isAlive());
    }
```

This passes, which is good. Which is not good is that I had to add sleep into the Deadlock class itself, and also in its test. I had to do this just in order to make the test consistently pass. Even though if I remove sleep from everywhere this code could sometimes produce a deadlock, but then there is no guarantee that it happens during the test. Now say having sleep is unacceptable here, then the question is:
How can I reliably test that this code, has a potential to cause a deadlock without any sleep neither in the test and in the actual code itself?

edit: I just wanted to emphasize that I am asking for the class to have a potential for a deadlock, only in some "unlucky" timing (when two threads are calling `method1()` and `method2()` at the same time) this deadlock should happen. And in my test, I want to demonstrate deadlock on every run. I  want to remove sleep calls from the production code (hopefully from the test also). Maybe there is a way to use mocks instead of the injected monitors, so we could orchestrate them acquiring locks in a specific order during the test?

Comment: There is no reliable test for potential deadlocks. Instrumenting code to trigger a known deadlock at a certain location might be possible, but where’s the sense in that?

Comment: you can use a tool https://github.com/devexperts/dlcheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you need `Thread (t1)` executing `method1` to wait inside `synchronized (monitor1)` but outside of`synchronized (monitor2)` until another `Thread (t2)` executing `method2` goes inside `synchronized (monitor2)` and releases `t1` and both threads try to proceed.

Or vice versa, where `t2` waits until `t1` comes and releases

You can code this scenario yourself. But since you are focusing just on `Deadlock` testing, you can use a `java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier` between `2 parties` to orchestrate this, where `parties` indicate the number of threads that must invoke `CyclicBarrier.await()` before the barrier is tripped (in other words, all the threads previous awaiting proceeds).

```
class Deadlock {
    final private CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    final private Object monitor1;
    final private Object monitor2;

    public Deadlock(Object monitor1, Object monitor2) {
        this.monitor1 = monitor1;
        this.monitor2 = monitor2;
    }

    public void method1() throws BrokenBarrierException, InterruptedException {
        synchronized (monitor1) {
            cyclicBarrier.await();
            synchronized (monitor2) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void method2() throws BrokenBarrierException, InterruptedException {
        synchronized (monitor2) {
            cyclicBarrier.await();
            synchronized (monitor1) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void tryToSleep(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to handle the checked Exceptions threw by `cyclicBarrier.await()`

```
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                deadlock.method1(); 
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        t1.start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                deadlock.method2();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        t2.start();

        deadlock.tryToSleep(5000); // Wait till all threads have a chance to become alive

        assertEquals(Thread.State.BLOCKED, t1.getState());
        assertTrue(t1.isAlive());

        assertEquals(Thread.State.BLOCKED, t2.getState());
        assertTrue(t2.isAlive());
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I wanted to test the **potential** for a Deadlock (something that only sometimes happens on production). And I want the test case to demonstrate that potential. Now it blocks every time, and even if I am calling only `method1()`, it is already blocked waiting for a barrier. Deadlock is not something called by a single thread, a single thread calling the method cannot block it. In the example with sleep, it was only deadlocking when two threads were calling those methods at the same time. Maybe is a way to mock monitors to simulate "unlucky" timing.